# How to synchronize between a thread on server and a thread on client side?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, client-server

My application creates threads for file transfer on both the server and client sides. Right now I'm using delaying tactics (a simple for loop) on client side so that thread creation in client is done *after* the thread creation process in server.

The app works fine. But this is crude, if not ugly. I need to find a technical way so that the client thread is not started until it knows that server thread has been started.

I tried to use a send() from server to the client. The client's `recv()` must block for server's signal but apparently it doesn't. The message on the client console is about connection being refused by the server. Any hints, please?

Comment: It won't block it the socket isn't connected.

Comment: I think you have to use separate tcp/udp connection for file transfer.

Comment: Are these threads in a single application, or in two different applications? You wrote "creates threads for file transfer on server and client sides", which sounds like you have seperate applications on seperate machines. If so, how are they started? Are the machines already communicating over another channel, when they start the file transfer threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select()` may be what you're looking for: you give it a set of sockets and it blocks until something happens on these sockets (and you can provide a timeout to avoid waiting forever).
Call `select()` to wait until data is received on the client side, then `recv()` to ensure what was received is the right message from the server.

Comment: I suggest using `poll` instead of `select` (see the *C10K* problem).

Answer (score 0):

Seems you use connectionless transport. In this case I would suggest playing ping-pong game, client sends "ping" udp packet to server in loop (with reasonable period) until client receives "pong" UDP packet from server or time out.